# TLS 1.1 error issues in sandbox

Tags: integration

Hi i got an issue with integrating with my .net application.
We had downloaded the wsdl file for our sandbox [image]and using in asp.net application while checking the both versions after try to login security keys.we face an issue called

UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organisation.please use TLS 1.1 or higher to connecting to salesforce

But,we have already disabled TLS 1.0 and enabled TLS 1.1.1.2 at the published server in the IIS/Registry as well as in the browser settings.

For reference:

I am attaching images

Comment: That error message seems to contradict itself. Did you copy it verbatim? `TLS 1.1 has been disabled in this organisation.please use TLS 1.1 or higher to connecting to salesforce`. TLS 1.1 should be allowed.

Comment: Which version of .Net are you compiling in? I had to go to 4.5.1 to get the TLS fix

Comment: Yes I am new to integration.we have other team they are saying they are already updated the server to TLS 1.1.and using 2012 4.5 version. @AdrianLarson